# Can't authenticate with spring security via DB

Tags: mysql, database, grails, spring-security

Was created a simple grails project and add spring security by tutorial (http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#tutorials). I skipped step 7 and 11, because I want store my data, username and password, in DB.

Create simple registration form and action in controller

```
def register(String username, String email, String password) {
    def user = new User(username: username, email: email, password: password)
    user.save(flush: true);
    def role = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER');
    UserRole.create user, role, true
}
```

I change my domain User

```
class User {

    String username
    String email
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
...
}
```

Registration work. In DB user exist - username, email etc. Role and UserRole empty.

When I try logged in I receive error message

> Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and
>   password.

I can't find how to fix this. Should I write my own action for logging? I read the documentation, but didn't found answers.

Thank you.

Comment: have you left that parts with the password encoding intact?  how can you be sure, that the user is saved in your register method?

Comment: Do you encode user password? Method which creates users should call:
password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)

Comment: That's all changes what I to do with code. I will try use encodePassword method when create user. I can't understand why this method need use in this case. As I remember, I don't have code now, this method exist in User class which generated with command s2-quickstart